# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, argumentnullexception

I have no idea where the `value` parameter comes from.

View: `Ajax.BeginForm` inquiry:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE, new SelectList(
                    new[] 
                    { 
                        new { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
                        new { Value = "false", Text = "No" },
                    },
                    "Value",
                    "Text",
                    Model
                ),
                "-- Select --")
```

After I choose yes or no in the drop down list, a partial view will be rendered for displaying data in a WebGrid (`grid` is an instance of `WebGrid`). One of the columns throws the error:

```
grid.Column("expenseReportable","Expense Reportable?",format:@<text>
<span class="display-mode">@item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE  </span> <!--error here -->
@Html.RadioButton("GridCol_Expense", (Nullable<bool>)item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE, true, new { @class="edit-mode"}) Yes        
@Html.RadioButton("GridCol_Expense", (Nullable<bool>)item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE, false, new { @class="edit-mode"}) No
                </text>, style:"col1Width"),
```

Model property:

```
public Nullable <bool> EXPENSE_REPORTABLE {get; set;}
```

InnerException: `null`

Exception Message:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value

Comment: The error is most likely because the value of `item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE` is `null` and is thrown on the following lines (the 2nd parameter of `RadioButton()` cannot be `null`). But the code for the radio butttons makes no sense anyway because your creating 2 radio buttons with the same value. Are you wanting radio  buttons to return `true` or `false`? (in which case you have the 2nd and 3rd parameters the wrong way around)

Comment: No, The 2nd parameter is the value of the radio button. If the value of `item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE` is say `true`, then you generating both radio buttons as `<input type="radio" ..... value="true" />` (which is a bit pointless) - but if the value of `item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE` is `null` then an exception will be thrown.

Comment: the radio buttons actually belong to the css class `edit-mode` which will not be display unless you hit the edit button.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. `@Html.RadioButton()` is razor code which is run on the server. If the value of `item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE` is `null` then that exception will be thrown. (and its documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobutton(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.RadioButton%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Object,System.Boolean%29))

Comment: Oh I see where the problem coming from. Is there anyway to throw the exception? Should I add a 3rd button for null value?

Comment: Not sure what you mean (it is throwing the exception). Your radio buttons make no sense, and I assume what you want is `@Html.RadioButton("GridCol_Expense", true, item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE, new { @class="edit-mode"}) Yes` and `@Html.RadioButton("GridCol_Expense", false, item.EXPENSE_REPORTABLE, new { @class="edit-mode"}) No` so that if you select the first, it will submit `true` and if you choose the second, it will submit false

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your `Global.asax` file.

You will see exception in detail, what went wrong.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // Attach break point here. 
    Exception TheError = Server.GetLastError(); //After execution of this line just check TheError variable. It will show you the details.
    Server.ClearError(); 
}
```

I suspect your objects `item` / `grid` might be null or it might has some null property. Just make sure its not null by debugging the server code itself.

Also its complicated to guess what is going wrong in your end and the conversation also going very long. Just Try this solution.

Hope this helps :)